# How to set up a conversion event for a Chrome Extension install?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-ads-api

The Chrome Web Store allows you to add a Google Analytics UA tracking number to your Chrome Extension's page, however I can't find a way to integrate it directly with Google Ads to be able to track installs -- and to be able to track what keywords lead to higher or lower install rates.

Is there a simple method of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you probably don't need to add any Google Ads codes. If you have your conversions in Google Analytics, you can connect Google Analytics with Google Ads aka "link" accounts. And after that you can add conversions from GA4 to Google Ads

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).